# How to open .json.gz format file and create dataframe n R?

Tags: r, json, dataframe, gzip

I have downloaded abcd.json.gz file. The file size is 10GB I want to parse it and create data frame from it in an efficient way. How to do it in R ?

Comment: You need to extract this file first and after did you already try some solutions from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/r/r_json_files.htm ?

Comment: I have already downloaded the file to local, Now I want to parse it and get data frame.

Comment: A simple as.data.frame doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I do it without unpacking the file first:

```
con <- gzfile("file.json.gz", "rt")
lines <- readLines(con)
close(con)
df <- jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(lines), verbose = FALSE)
```

This uses line-by-line processing of JSON, which is the only JSON format I've encountered in the wild so far.

Comment: @ JB Gruber this works, but the file to be read is of size 10GB. so it is taking a long time. any other solution?

Comment: I don't think you can speed this up significantly if you want the whole file as `data.frame`. Do you maybe just want to read part of the file?